# How to load UIView .xib with corner radius and shadow into main viewcontroller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to creating custom `UIView` with some attributes like `corner radius`, `shadow`, and `button action` `title label`. This is I am maintaining in a common class. I need to call from multiple different `viewcontroller`. I can call this from viewcontroller but don’t know how to maintain shadow, corner radius into `customview` class. How to achieve this like a popup and call from multiple view controllers.

**My CustomView Class**

```
import UIKit

class ToastView: UIView {    

}
```

**My CustomView .Xib**

[image]

**ViewController To Calling CustomView**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ToastView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ToastView
        view.addSubview(customView)
        customView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width-50, height: 55.0)
        customView.center = view.center
        customView.layer.borderColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        customView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        customView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take layer attributes like `shadow` and `cornerRadius` logic into the `view`'s class itself:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    layer.borderColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
    layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
}
```

So now it always have those.

Note that `clipsToBounds` kills `shadow`.

Comment: Thank you :) May I know how to set frames also inside views class? Because every time calling view from main view controller no need to replicate frame size

Comment: You can use `didMoveToSuperview()`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. I am going to maintain one label and button inside the UIView. How to call this view and before that how to set frame size into this custom class? Its kind of a toast popup for ios

Comment: how to change this two lines in one line? I need to show this view below navigation bar `customView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width-50, height: 55.0)
        customView.center = view.center`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Extension` to add shadow

```
import UIKit

class AnyViewController: UIViewController {
    //Your necessary methods & properties
    //call your xib here
}

extension UIView {

    func addShadow(offset: CGSize, color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat, opacity: Float)
    {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowOffset = offset
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity

        let backgroundCGColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
        backgroundColor = nil
        layer.backgroundColor =  backgroundCGColor
    }
}
```

you can call it like

```
your_Custom_View.layer.cornerRadius = 20 //to add corner radius
your_Custom_View.addShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 1), color: UIColor.black, radius: 2.0, opacity: 1.0) //to add shadow
```

Comment: I am using .xib how to set this?

Comment: I think you have to edit your answer. Where I need to place extension inside customViewclass or main viewcontroller ?

Comment: You can add the extension in any ViewController

Comment: you have to write the extension outside of the class @myappstore

Comment: I am using .xib. how this makes simple?

Comment: check it now @myappstore

Comment: Can i use this extension inside custom class because I am going to call this view from multiple viewcontroller. So, if its common one then thats good practice right?

Comment: you can add the extension in any view controller of course out side of the class & you can call it from anywhere